# How to implement setOnClickListener on Button and also pass touch to other views

Tags: android

How can I implement setOnClickListener for a button and also pass the touches to other view and not absorb them ?

This is my current implementation and it absorbs touches

```
button.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public  void onClick (android.view.View v) {
               Log.d(TAG, "i am clicked");
              }
       });
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'pass the touches to other view and not absorb them'?

Answer (score 1):

You can return `false` from `onTouch()`. Like this:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new android.view.View.OnTouchListener() {
       @Override
       public  void onTouch (android.view.View v) {
               Log.d(TAG, "i am touched");
               return false;
              }
       });
```

As per the Android [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html)

```
This returns a boolean to indicate whether your listener consumes this event. The
important thing is that this event can have multiple actions that follow each other. So, if 
you return false when the down action event is received, you indicate that you have not 
consumed the event and are also not interested in subsequent actions from this event.
```

Answer (score 1):

I Believe that you want to make an other button clicked with the same input.
The way to do it is this:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public  void onClick (android.view.View v) {
           Log.d(TAG, "i am clicked");
           button2.performClick();
          }
   });
```